# How do I make my list into a dataframe if rbind.fill always returns null?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this list:

```
myList<-list(c("Developmental Biology", " Neuroscience", " Cell Biology"
), c("Developmental Biology", " Neuroscience", " Cell Biology"
), c("Developmental Biology", " Neuroscience", " Genomics & Genetics"
), c("Developmental Biology", " Neuroscience", " Cell Biology"
), c("Developmental Biology", " Neuroscience", " Cell Biology"
), c("Developmental Biology", " Genomics & Genetics"))
```

I want this dataframe:

```
     [,1]                    [,2]                   [,3]                   
[1,] "Developmental Biology" " Neuroscience"        " Cell Biology"        
[2,] "Developmental Biology" " Neuroscience"        " Cell Biology"        
[3,] "Developmental Biology" " Neuroscience"        " Genomics & Genetics" 
[4,] "Developmental Biology" " Neuroscience"        " Cell Biology"        
[5,] "Developmental Biology" " Neuroscience"        " Cell Biology"        
[6,] "Developmental Biology" " Genomics & Genetics" "NA"
```

I would have thought rbind.fill would be the way to go, but `do.call(rbind.fill,myList)` returns `NULL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `rbind.fill` can only combine data frames. But the elements in the list `myList` are character vectors. They need to be transformed to data frames before using `rbind.fill`.

This does the trick:

```
library(plyr)
rbind.fill(lapply(myList, function(x) as.data.frame(t(as.matrix(x)))))

#                      V1                   V2                   V3
# 1 Developmental Biology         Neuroscience         Cell Biology
# 2 Developmental Biology         Neuroscience         Cell Biology
# 3 Developmental Biology         Neuroscience  Genomics & Genetics
# 4 Developmental Biology         Neuroscience         Cell Biology
# 5 Developmental Biology         Neuroscience         Cell Biology
# 6 Developmental Biology  Genomics & Genetics                 <NA>
```